# MAMP OS X 10.8.2 Virtual Hosts

Tags: macos, mamp, virtualhost

I am attempting to set up MAMP on my Macbook Pro, and I cannot seem to get a virtual host running. This is my first attempt at this.  I am coming from a WAMP/Windows 7 environment, so I may have passed over something.  I have already followed the guides on the MAMP site, and a couple others rendered from Google searches, but to no avail...

My /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
127.0.0.1 robabby
```

My httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/admin/Development/websites/robabby"
    ServerName robabby
</VirtualHost>
```

I followed the MAMP GUI for setting up a new host.
[image]

Direct my browser to robabby:80 and I get a `ERROR: 500 (internal server error)`
[image]

Any help much appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different server setups here

1 / listening on port 80 (but you should check that, just try "http://127.0.0.1:80"

2 / listening on port 8888 (that's the server returning the error message)

Your built-in server defaults to 80, Mamp is listening on port 8888.

Are there two different lots of config files or is Mamp supposed to take over the built-in Apache?

You need to work that out.

Meanwhile

- just try robabby:80
- try changing your virtualhost to 8888

_

```
 NameVirtualHost *:8888


<VirtualHost *:8888>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/admin/Development/websites/robabby"
    ServerName robabby
</VirtualHost>
```

But I think you are getting two server set-ups confused...

Comment: Mmmk, I tried both suggestions, plus a couple more. Setting the `NameVirtualHost` to `8888` did not work.  Not only that, but navigating to `localhost:8888` brings up the MAMP Virtual Host start page. `robabby:8888` was still `Error 500`. I reverted its back to `*:80` and set MAMP to default to that port as well.  navigating to `localhost:80` brings up MAMP virtual host page. Navigating to `robabby:80` brings up the `500` error again.

Comment: Silly me, it had nothing to do with the virtual host, and everything to do with an incompatibility with the PHP files in my imported site.  I am assuming some issue dealing with the ROOT relative directory for the includes in my PHP website.  Tested with a static HTML Hello World webpage and it worked just fine.  Thanks a ton for the response and trying to help!